# How to reduce horizontal spacing between columns in a custom list environment?

Tags: tables

I am tweaking my CV and I am defining a custom list environment. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{ragged2e}
    
\pagestyle{empty}
      
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rl}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{10.00cm}{\strut%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3\par}%no!\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{entrylist}
    
\entry
   {Office}
   {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
   {}
   {}
  
\entry
   {Website}
   {www.somename.com}
   {}
   {}
    
 \entry
   {Email}
   {somename a aaa}
   {}
   {}
   
 \entry
   {Phone}
   {+00 0000 000000}
   {}
   {}
  
\end{entrylist}
    
\end{document}
```

The MWE generates the following output:

[image]

The only problem that I have is the amount of white space between the left and the right columns. I need to reduce the spacing between both columns without affecting the 10cm length specified in `#1&\parbox[t]{10.00cm}{\strut%` nor the textwidth specified in `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rl}`. Essentially, I just need the left column to be closer to the right column. **Can anybody help me reduce the white space between both columns?**

**EDIT**

After the comments, I realised my question may have an unclear wording, so let me try again. Im my document, I call several `entrylists`. I need all such `entrylists` to satisfy two conditions:

(1) the same, reasonable separation between left & right columns;

(2) the white space between columns to be horizontally aligned.

I don’t seem to be able to achieve (1) & (2) simultaneously. Either I get a reasonable separation between right and left columns or I get the right column to be correctly aligned across `entrylists`. But, no matter what I try, I don’t seem to get both (1) & (2) at the same time.

I show here why David Carlisle’s answer achieves (1) but not (2). In his answer, David suggests to have:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{ragged2e}
    
\pagestyle{empty}
      
    \newenvironment{entrylist}{%
      \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}rl}
    }{%
      \end{tabular}
    }
    \renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
    \newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
      #1&\parbox[t]{10.00cm}{\strut%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {\footnotesize #3\par}%no!\\%
        #4\vspace{\parsep}%
      }\\}
    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{entrylist}
    
\entry
   {Office}
   {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
   {}
   {}
  
\entry
   {Website}
   {www.somename.com}
   {}
   {}
    
 \entry
   {Email}
   {somename a aaa}
   {}
   {}
   
 \entry
   {Phone}
   {+00 0000 000000}
   {}
   {}
  
\end{entrylist}

\begin{entrylist}
    
\entry
   {Longer name}
   {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
   {}
   {}
  
\entry
   {Much much longer name}
   {www.somename.com}
   {}
   {}
    
 \entry
   {Email}
   {somename a aaa}
   {}
   {}
   
 \entry
   {Phone}
   {+00 0000 000000}
   {}
   {}
  
\end{entrylist}
    
\end{document}
```

The output that is generated satisfies (1) but not (2), because the column separation in the first environment is not aligned with the column separation in the second environment. See the output:

[image]

I am really sorry for not having worded my question better since the beginning —my bad.

Thank you all for your time.

**EDIT** I now show how Bernard’s answer achieves the desired output but alters the spacing before a section title. He suggests to have something like

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
    
\pagestyle{empty}
      
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}r@{\enspace}l@{}}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \eqmakebox[H][r]{#1}&\parbox[t]{10.00cm}{\strut%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3\par}%no!\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
  
\begin{document}
    
\begin{entrylist}
    
\entry
   {Office}
   {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
   {}
   {}
  
\entry
   {Website}
   {www.somename.com}
   {}
   {}
    
 \entry
   {Email}
   {somename a aaa}
   {}
   {}
   
 \entry
   {Phone}
   {+00 0000 000000}
   {}
   {}
  
\end{entrylist}

\section*{Whatever fancy title you can think of}

\begin{entrylist}
    
\entry
   {Longer name}
   {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
   {}
   {}
  
\entry
   {Much much longer name}
   {www.somename.com}
   {}
   {}
    
 \entry
   {Email}
   {somename a aaa}
   {}
   {}
   
 \entry
   {Phone}
   {+00 0000 000000}
   {}
   {}
  
\end{entrylist}
    
 \end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

You can check that the subtitle is lower when compared with the original code:

[image]

I don’t know why Bernard’s answer lowers the title, but I suspect it may have something to do with the `eqparbox` package.

Comment: In this case, don't use `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`.

Comment: You are specifying `{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r`  that is force the columns as far apart as possible. use `tabular` not `tabular*` and delete `{\textwidth}`

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, erasing `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` is not what I am looking for. That line is there to ensure that all my list environments are aligned, since I have many such environments in the same document. If I delete that line, the left column in each list environment moves to the left. The problem is then two-fold: the lack of space makes it ugly and not all list environments are equally aligned, since their alignment depends on the content of the first column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, doing what you suggest destroys the entire document in unexpected ways. Either that, or I am not understanding your suggestion (which could well be the case).

Comment: no that is not what it does. The only thing that does is force the two columns in this table to be as far apart as possible. You can use `@{}` to have no space in the left or as I say leave it if you use tabular and delete `{\textwidth}` the extracolseop will do nothing

Comment: ouch you have `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` ! OK you need to add a bit of space back if you hav ethat, are you sure you want that?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What I want is all my custom list environments to have the same amount of horizontal separation between left & right columns while ensuring that the white space between both columns keeps the same horizontal alignment across environments. Did my explanation make sense?

Comment: oh maybe you want `\hspace*{\fill}\begin{tabular}` so that the table is flush right as you have a fixed width right hand column

Comment: If you want to align multiple "lists" you need to fix the width of both columns.  The \parbox fixes the right column at 10cm, but the left column can be anything.  Another \parbox or \makebox will do.  In fact, you wouldn't even need a tabular.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, John. I am currently fixing the width of both columns. My last remaining problem is to specify the length of the right column such that the table spans the entire width of the document, which has a 2cm margins up, down, left & right. Any clue on how to do that?

Comment: You can use something like `{\dimexpr \linewidth-10cm-\columnsep}` for the width of the left column.  You may need a `\noindent`.

Comment: Thank you. Between yours and David’s comments, I finally got it fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forcing the two columns as far apart as possible using `\extracolsep` so the natural thing to do is to use `tabular` not `tabular*` and use the natural separation so

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}rl}
```

However that produces

[image]

due to your setting of

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
```

which says that by default table columns should touch with no separation.

If you delete that line you get

[image]

Or if you need that for other parts of the document add some space with eg

```
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{5pt}}l}
```

or whatever space you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I can’t accept it because it doesn’t achieve what I am asking for in my original question. Your answer achieves goal (1) but not goal (2) in my original question. I will now edit my original question so you can see it doesn’t achieve (2). I am sorry for the poor wording of my question, which is probably the culprit of the mess.

Comment: you could specify the width of the left column  or as I mentioned put `\hspace*{\fill}` before the tabular and rely on the (effective but unusually specified) fixed width of the right column.

Comment: you could replace `l` by `p{3cm}` or whatever width (you could do the second column the same way rather than a nested `\parbox`)  or if you have loaded `array` package you can specify the width of an `l` column by using `wl{3cm}` @Héctor

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful. I only have one remaining question: how can I specify the length of the right column to occupy all available space (i.e., until the 2cm margin set through geometry).

Comment: well since you have specified tabcolsep is zero that's simple arithmetic its \dimexpr\textwidth-3cm` or whatever size you specified for the first instead if `10.00cm`  (but I don't know why you used `\parbox` in an `l` column rather than use a \p` column although it doesn't make much difference

Comment: I can no longer do the simple arithmetic you propose because I followed your initial suggestion and erased the `tablecolsep=0`. Hence, I don’t know the amount of white space between left & right columns.

Comment: well subtract 4\tabcolsep  or 3 if you have used `@{}` to remove the padding from the start. each column has `\tabcolsep` padding either side

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, you’ll have to excuse my ignorance… Could you please further indicate where to subtract `4\tablecolsep` from in the code?

Comment: change 10cm to `\dimexpr\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-3cm`  if 3cm is the width of the first column, @Héctor

Comment: I ended up using `\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2cm` because the first column is 2cm wide. The reason why I need `2\tablecolsep` rather than `4\tablecolsep` remains a mystery to me. But I know that with my current choice of values, I get the correct width. Also, I have massively relied on your expertise to get this done, but the answer you provide is not exactly the one I am using in my code. What should we do —shall you update your answer or shall I answer my own question? I’d rather give you the points of the accepted answer, but I’ll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a poossible solution with `eqparbox` and a table preamble without `@\extracolsep`. However I think the simplest solution, as regards possible page breaks, would be to define a custom description environment with `enumitem`.
\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}r@{\enspace}l@{}}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \eqmakebox[H][r]{#1}&\parbox[t]{10.00cm}{\strut%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3\par}%no!\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{entrylist}

\entry
   {Office}
   {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
   {}
   {}

\entry
   {Website}
   {www.somename.com}
   {}
   {}

 \entry
   {Email}
   {somename a aaa}
   {}
   {}

 \entry
   {Phone}
   {+00 0000 000000}
   {}
   {}

\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While your solution achieves both (1) & (2), it modified the vertical spacing before the titles of the subsections (although I don’t know the reason why). Hence, I can’t accept it.

Comment: I didn't change whatever to the vertical spacing, and I don't understand what happens. Could you post a small compilable code illustrating this difference?

Comment: I just edited my question following your request.